# Trying to figure out a script to stop a process under a specific user over the local network using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need a script to terminate a process that is running by a specific user over the local network.

I used

```
(get-wmiobject Win32_process -ComputerName thepcname | 
   ? {$_.ProcessName -match "notepad" }).Terminate()
```

but need it to be user specified as well. Please how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Get-Process -ComputerName thepcname -IncludeUserName
```

then filter by `$_.UserName`

Note this will require admin permissions.

Comment: I tried this from a windows 10 os to a win7 and it returned an error and did not recognize -IncludeUserName

Comment: Thank you for the response too by the way :)

Comment: Probaly an older powershell version then. I don't really use remoting myself tbh. But there are some good resources out there if you do a little research. And we'll be here to help with the details.

Comment: What would the syntax look like if I filtered with $_.Username?

Comment: @RobPilon `? {$_.ProcessName -match "notepad" -and $_.UserName -eq $username }`

Comment: So greatful thank you so much!

Comment: Ok so I have tried this and it does not work. Here is the scenario: I have a small POS network, one main server and several terminals and tablets all with their own station numbers. Each terminal and tablet has users. I am trying find a script that when logged into the server it will find the tablet name followed by the username and stop a process running by a user on that tablet. Is this possible?

Comment: @RobPilon "does not work" is never a helpful description. Please be more accurate. Also, you might have more luck on Serverfault, because Stackoverflow is about coding, not administration.